# pass field value to button - map it button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i want to be able to click in the map it buttom and open external page in google maps page size 500 X 600 no Menu bar, Tool bar
,Status bar.

```js
// Get Button by salahineo
let button = document.getElementById('map');
// On Button Click
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
// Get Inputs
let address = document.getElementById('address');
let city = document.getElementById('city');
// Go To Google Map Search Location Based On Input Values
window.open(`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${address.value}%2C${city.value}`);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="1001 Rose Bowl Dr">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="Pasadena">
<button id="map">Map it</button>
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=">Map it</a>
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add event listener on click to button
2. Get Input Values
3. Open new window with google map search based on input values

```js
// Get Button
let button = document.getElementById('map');
// On Button Click
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
// Get Inputs
let address = document.getElementById('address');
let city = document.getElementById('city');
// Go To Google Map Search Location Based On Input Values
window.open(`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${address.value}%2C${city.value}`);
})
```

Comment: the button works amazing, im upgrading to link instead, would u help?  i update it.

Comment: 1. Remove or comment button
2. Make href of link = #
3. Give the link id 'map'

`<a id="map" href="#">Map it</a>`

This will make the link do the same role of the button

Comment: thanks again, its working but im using in in wordpress somehow the ${address.value} $ is giving me issues, can i use something alse? jQuery Did no work when i replace it

Comment: Yes, you can use a concatenation operator instead, and it will not produce any error.
`window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + address.value + "%2C" + city.value);
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look into leaflet.js from https://leafletjs.com/

Here is the example of search that you want to create from leaflet.js that are created by @exomark in codepen

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/exomark/pen/dafBD)
```